# How to resize the div size over an image?

Tags: html, css

I am having more div over an image.and i am having zoom in and zoom out option to resize the image.when i resize an image, i want to resize the divs present over an image. How to achieve it using HTML and css.

Comment: can you provide screenshots or link to your code to make it easy to understand your problem?

Comment: Use JavaScript...

Comment: can u give code pls?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -2):

The image needs to be placed as a background of a div and the other divs then need to be positioned absolutely against that div e.g. like this: